# Azure .net core app service does not run from Package

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-app-service-envrmnt, azure-appservice

I deploy my application using azure pipeline.
First build using dotnet build, then publish, then Deploy

```
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\DQMIntegration\'
    ArtifactName: 'DQMIntegration'
    publishLocation: 'Container'

- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  inputs:
    ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
    azureSubscription: 'DQM-NonProd'
    appType: 'webApp'
    WebAppName: 'stg-DQMIntegration'
    deployToSlotOrASE: true
    ResourceGroupName: 'ESSP-N-1-QTYF-RG-2'
    SlotName: 'production'
    packageForLinux: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/DQMIntegration/'
```

The deployment sets WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE=1 in the Azure app service. However, the application does not run.

Application shows Running in Azure console in both cases.

I have no specific requirement to run from package or otherwise, but I can't understand why the application does not run form package or why the pipeline sets it so. In the kudu console I see that the zip file has been uploaded in data/SitePackages and there is a packagename.txt file with the name of the latest uploaded zip.
My app service is in an ASE. it is a c sharp API.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi @Tauqir, if the solution did some help, do you mind accepting it as the answer for others to refer?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, **Run From Package** is different with **ZIP Depoly**.

What you are doing is ZIP Deploy, you don't need to add `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE` in app settings. This environment variable would make the file under wwwroot Read-Only, and `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE="1"` lets you run your app from a package **local** to your app, so set it's value to be `'1'` only when you want to run your application from local package.

If you wan run from a remote package, you can do this:  `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE=url`

> Because the WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE app setting is set, this command doesn't extract the package content to the D:\home\site\wwwroot directory of your app. Instead, it uploads the ZIP file as-is to D:\home\data\SitePackages, and creates a packagename.txt in the same directory, that contains the name of the ZIP package to load at runtime. If you upload your ZIP package in a different way (such as FTP), you need to create the D:\home\data\SitePackages directory and the packagename.txt file manually.

Yes, it should run if the file in kudu is correct. Since you are not using run from package, the `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE="1"` cannot find the file it need, it is the reason of the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I am claer about these two features. WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE has these two settings. Url can be given if your zip file is in, let's say Azure storage. setting it to 1 runs it from the location where it has been uploaded /home//data/SitePackages. There is another file packagename.txt in that place that points to the zip file that should be run.

Comment: Definitely you are right. The point is how it works when we set `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE="1"`. I have update my answer, hope it help a little bit.